# Application going in background -- Home button tapped when application is running

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

What is the sequence of methods that gets called when we tap on the home button on iPhone, i.e. when an application is going in background.

Basically, I want to make a server call before my app goes in background. I am writing my server call code in `applicationWillResignActive:`, but sometimes it executes and sometimes it doesn't.

I need a solution for this.

Comment: What devices are `applicationWillResignActive:` not calling on? If it is a non-multitasking device, then that will not call, you need `applicationWillTerminate:` instead.

Comment: That's the right call.  Is applicationWillTerminate: called?  Is your UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend set to NO at all times?

Comment: Try applicationDidEnterBackground as well.  Also, although the simulator and device usually restore my debugging session when reopening, this has not been consistent.

Answer (score 0):

From the app delegate file itself:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
     If your application supports background execution, called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

     Superclass implementation saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
     */
    [super applicationDidEnterBackground:application];
}
```

Try using this method.....